# Как узнать владельца сервера Discord с помощью Discord.NET?

Tags: c#, discord, discord-api

Я пишу недобота на C# с либой Discord.NET и мне нужно узнать овнера сервера в евенте JoinedGuild(SocketGuildUser user), помогите дурачку пожалуйста.

Comment: и минусы не ставьте пж, только изучаю либу

Comment: Не работал с дискордом, но думаю легче получить фулл инфу о сервере а потом уже просто вытащить свойства какие-то, 100% будут флаги вроде "IsAdmin" или типа того

Comment: Эвент, который вы назвали, отдает вам `SocketGuild`, а не `SocketGuildUser`. А в этом объекте есть `Owner` и `OwnerId`.